# Python split by exact substring?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I want to take a markdown document and split it by the headers. First by h1, then h2, then h3.

So for the first split I need to split by the symbol `#` but only if it is completely isolated, so neither `##` nor `###` should be considered separators. This is doable if I coded my own method, but that adds verbosity I would like to avoid if possible.

I tried using word boundaries and regexes, but word boundaries don't count for symbols such as `#`

For example:

```
# Tests
Located at `Tests/`

## `main.cpp`
### `int AddOne(int num)`

 * **Param:** `num` Satisfies $\text{num} \in [-\infty,\infty]$.
### `int AddOne(int num)`

 * **Param:** `num` Satisfies $\text{num} \in [-\infty,\infty]$.
### `int AddOne(int num)`

 * **Param:** `num` Satisfies $\text{num} \in [-\infty,\infty]$.
```

That should first be split into an array containing the empty string and an array containing the rest of the document.

Then the non null part is split into an array containing the top part and everything after `main.cpp`.

Finally the last element of the prior array is split into 3 different parts.
Then into a

Is this doable with standard methods?

Comment: Regex is the better tool for the job. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, edited the question, word boundaries do not apply to special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/re-syntax.html) and negative lookahead/lookbehind assertions:

```
import re

re.split(r"(?<!#)#(?!#)", "abc#def##ghi###jkl")
# ['abc', 'def##ghi###jkl']

re.split(r"(?<!#)##(?!#)", "abc#def##ghi###jkl")
# ['abc#def', 'ghi###jkl']
```

Comment: Because the search progresses left to right, the lookbehind should be unnecessary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I checked it, and both are required. The first of two `#` would match without the lookbehind and the last of them would match without lookahead.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.